# Golang - what's the correct order to check error and defer an operation?

Tags: http, go

I'm new to Go. If I'm doing an HTTP get request let this:

```
resp, err := http.Get("https://www.google.com")
```

Now I need to check whether `err` is nil and `defer resp.Body.Close()`. What's the correct order to do these two operations?

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference since the close call is deferred. It seems to be idiomatic to check the error first and then defer the close.

Comment: @Sridhar: This is **wrong**! if err!=nil then resp == nil in which case the defered Body.Close() will panic.

Comment: Yikes you're right - just tried it. Obviously never come across this because I handle all my errors straight away :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to check for error right after the call to `Get`. If `Get` fails, `resp` will be set to `nil`. This means that `resp.Body` would generate runtime `nil pointer dereferenced` error.

```
resp, err := http.Get("https://www.google.com")
if err != nil {
    // process error
    return err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```